# cakephp complex find

Tags: cakephp, find

I would like to find all the news(actus) about a followed user when a customer is connected.

I created these tables

**User**
id
username
created

**Follows**
id
user_id
follow_id

**Actus**
id
user_id
content
created

Model User is linked to Follow and Actu by a Hasmany jointure

I try this but it doesn't seem to work

```
 $this->Follow->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array('Follow.user_id' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')),
        'contain' => array('User' => array('Actu','conditions'=>array('User.id = Follow.follow_id')))));
```

someone can help me please?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is the query generated, and what is incorrect about the query generated?

Answer (score 0):

I think your association needs modification (Modify your model and table)

put 
follow_id in Actus table then Follows table related into Actus table and confirm table name is Users

You need association like Follows hasmany Actus and Follows belongs to users

If you have all the correct associations then you can have the find query likr this

```
$this->Follow->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('Follow.user_id' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')));
```

please check this this

1. Make sure table name is Users
2. put follow_id in Actus table
3. Make sure the associations

Comment: The table "Actu" is a kind of user actions timeline so I can't put follow_id in Actus table because it will have many follow_id's for one entry

Comment: follow_id means id of follows table right or what follow_id represents for?

Comment: it represent the id of the followed user :-( I know tha name is not appropriate

Comment: Hi Did you corrected the table name into users and Follow table has already an association with user table?then how it possible to have another association, i think that logic has some problem.Because Follows table belongs to user table(using user id field)

Comment: Ok is it working now?and what about your models these are your associations right users belongsto follows,users belongsto actus,follows hasmany users, actus belongsto users

Comment: No it still not working please see my answer you will find the result of the query

Answer (score 0):

Here is the result

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Follow] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 12
                    [user_id] => 2
                    [followed_id] => 21
                )

```
        [User] => Array
            (
                [id] => 21
                [username] => isabelle
                [mail] => isabelle@
                [password] => 0469e87ef6441742744443fd1fc10f6bf59ee238
                [created] => 2012-04-24 15:28:07
                [lastlogin] => 2012-11-30 17:22:24
                [active] => 1
                [firstname] => Isabelle
                [lastname] =>
                [avatar] => 1335274087.jpg
                [age] => 29
                [town] => Paris
                [url] => 
                [Actu] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 2
                                [user_id] => 2
                                [content] => <a href="/users/view/2">rti</a> a post&eacute; un message sur la page <a href="/events/view/4"></a>
                                [created] => 2012-11-30 11:23:23
                            )
```